# Javascript code breaks with loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have been trying to do this for class, but I cannot seem to get it to work.  I need to have radio buttons to choose one of 4 coins.  q,d,n,p.  Then a select box with value up to 10.  When I change the select, Java needs to add the selected amount of coins, and show total, and display that many coins.  I have the add part down, but when I add the loop, it breaks the addition part of the project.  I don't know if I have the loop right, but right now I would like to know why my code breaks when I add the loop?  Code I have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doCalculate() {
        //Variable for calculation
        Q = document.getElementById('txtMoney').value;

        //If statements for selecting the correct radiobutton
        if (document.getElementById('rbQ').checked) {
            answer = Q * .25;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('rbD').checked) {
            answer = Q * .10;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('rbN').checked) {
            answer = Q * .05;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('rbP').checked) {
            answer = Q * .01;
        }


        //show results
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "$ " + answer + "<br>Dollars and Cents"


        //variables for coins using ID txtMoney from Select
        loopCounter = document.getElementById('txtMoney').value

        //If radio of coin is checked and loopcounter is higher then 0 run for loop
        if (document.getElementById('rbQ').checked && loopCounter > 0;) {
            document.getElementById('quarter').src = "quarter.gif";

        }

        resultsString = ""

        //for loop to count via select box value, and display that many images
        // of which ever coins radio is checked.
        for (x = 0; x < loopCounter; x++) {
            resultsString = loopCounter + quarter.gif
            //write to results2 via innerHTML
            document.getElementById('results2').innerHTML = resultsString;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the Java code?

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after initializing `loopCounter`. You're also missing one after `document.getElementById('results)'`. And at second glance also some others... And in one of the if statement there's an unneeded semi-colon.Also be aware that JavaScript != Java

Comment: Can you post the accompanying HTML?

Comment: That fixed it , thanks so much.  I am still learning, but I appreciate the help.  I was just getting so frustrated why if i commented it out, it worked, but when I added it, it didn't.  I even ran it through the markup validation at w3school, but it didn't find the missing semi-colon.  Thanks agian.  I feel stupid now because of something so small.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing string delimiters when you assign a value to `resultsString`, so the code will loop for the `gif` property in the `quarter` object, which naturally doesn't exist.

```
resultsString = loopCounter + "quarter.gif";
```

You have a semicolon too much inside the `if` condition before the loop:

```
if (document.getElementById('rbQ').checked && loopCounter>0) {
```